# Live database migration MariaDB 10.5 to MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-replication, live-migration

I need to  move a busy OLTP database from self hosted *MariaDB 10.5* to *Google Cloud SQL for MySQL 8.0* with minimal downtime.

The source is a self managed VM instance in Googles Cloud with replicas, ProxySQL as load balancer, etc. The destination is a Google Cloud SQL. The databse is ~400 GiB on disk and it takes about four hours to load it from a logicak dump.

I used to do this with replication and switchover, but MySQL 8.0 can't read the binary logs from MariaDB.

I would be grateful for any advice on how this move can be implemented with less than 10 minutes of downtime.

Comment: Try asking on dba.stackexchange.com .